# Database design ... distantly related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

Let's say I have three models:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent
    has_many :grandchildren
end

class Grandchild < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :children
end
```

I will be doing alot of queries to find the grandchildren of parent. Is it most efficient to do the multiple joins, or would it be better to add another relation to `Parent` to `has_many: :grandchildren` and `Grandchild` to `belongs_to :parent`? It seems like that would bring in the possibility of the models getting out of sync, although in this particular application, the relationships would never change once established.

Also, what if we were talking about models more distantly related ... say three or four joins away?

UPDATE: To clarify, what I'm modeling isn't really parents/children/grandchildren. I thought more generic names would make it clearer but I can see how these generic ones actually made it more confusing. It's more like company has products has parts has orders, and I need to find the orders related to a company. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: a recursive structure is probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

What about great-grandchildren? Etc.

You want a [self-join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) on a generic "person" class.

In addition, there are things like `acts_as_tree` or [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry), with a variety of implementations, that make such things trivial. Some optimize for retrieval and can load an entire hierarchy in a single call.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using self-joins and ancestry in other places. I was just trying to use some generic names for my question. There really isn't any type of ancestry in this particular part. It's more like a company produces a product that has parts that have orders. So I want to find all the orders related to a particular company.

Comment: The "exploded bill of materials" case lends itself perfectly to recursive structure. Getting the constraints right can be difficult.

Comment: @Brenda IMO the question is misleading then; YMMV. I'd use SQL directly to get to a company's orders. Or, more likely, I'd create either an auxiliary table to short-cut company -> orders, or give orders a company.